# Sed/Awk:How to remove Ctrl z characters at the last line, replace new line characters in between records to space

Tags: awk, sed

I have a requirement where I need to perform following 3 things to a file in Linux:

1. Check if Ctrl-z character is present at the last line of the file and if present then delete the line.
2. Replace new line characters that appear in between the fields in all the records to a single space but it should not replace the last new line in every record which signifies record delimiter.
3. Delete the first line of the file.

I can not use any script.Can it be done with sed/awk. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: to question 1: with GNU sed: `sed '${/\x1a/d}' file` to question 3: `sed '1d' file`

Comment: @srp can you explain more the 2nd question it's not clear it will be good if you can give us an example

Comment: Explain what `I can not use any script` means in light of `Can it be done with sed/awk.` - that's like saying `I cannot eat bread, can you pass me the toast.`, Also edit your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected but use some character other than ctrl-z for ease of copy/paste.